# how to make url unique when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have code like this in a page called list.php when i click a link the video in the iframe was change into the video i selected but in the address bar its still list.php how can i make the url be list.php/Anohana10? or something like that?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#videos li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#video").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    })
});
</script>

<div class="videoWrapper">
    <IFRAME  id="video" SRC="http://upload4free.co/embed-trdcgvsgf0tj-500x300.html" FRAMEBORDER=0  
        webkitAllowFullScreen ></IFRAME>
    </div>

<ul id="videos">
    <li><a id="Anohana10" href="http://upload4free.co/embed-ndi71khpdvbf-580x300.html">Anohana Episode 10</a></li>
    <li><a id="Anohana9" href="http://upload4free.co/embed-flm2y2648udr-580x300.html">Anohana Episode 9</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, instead of intercepting the `<a>`'s default behaviour of redirecting the page, let it anchor the information, like `<a id="Anohana10" href="#Anohana10">`, then your page's url would look like: `list.php#Anohana10`.

The iframe's link information, you can store on another custom attribute (let's say `data-url`), and retrieve it with your jquery function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#videos li a").click(function(e) {
        $("#video").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-url"));
    })
});
</script>

<div class="videoWrapper">
    <IFRAME  id="video" SRC="http://upload4free.co/embed-trdcgvsgf0tj-500x300.html" FRAMEBORDER=0  
        webkitAllowFullScreen ></IFRAME>
    </div>

<ul id="videos">
    <li><a id="Anohana10" href="#Anohana10" data-url="http://upload4free.co/embed-ndi71khpdvbf-580x300.html">Anohana Episode 10</a></li>
    <li><a id="Anohana9" href="#Anohana9" data-url="http://upload4free.co/embed-flm2y2648udr-580x300.html">Anohana Episode 9</a></li>
```

**EDIT**

To get the anchor from the URL when typing it directly, add this to the `ready` jquery method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var identifier = window.location.hash;
    if(identifier != "")
        $(identifier).click();

    $("ul#videos li a").click(function(e) {
    ...
});
```

This will get the `#id` from the url, and perform the click of the corresponding `<a>` tag, loading the video...

Comment: hi, thanks!!! it worked!! but i'm wondering why when i copy that url with list.ph#Anohana10, it doesn't actually go to that specific video? its still in the initial video when you load the list.php.

Comment: sorry but where to exactly i insert that?? i tried like this and the outcome was you have to enter the url twice to take effect? is that  normal? i mean i copy paste then enter to a new tab then i have to hit enter again to load the correct video on the correct  url?  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#videos li a").click(function(e) {
  
        $("#video").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-url"));
    })
var identifier = window.location.hash;
if(identifier != "")
    $(identifier).click();

Comment: Put the code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` declaration... Right before the `$("ul#videos li a").click(`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#videos li a").click(function(e) {
        $("#video").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-url"));
    })
var identifier = window.location.hash;
    if(identifier != "")
        $(identifier).click();
});    it worked like this for me,, thanks for your help...

Comment: another question if i may??...can i also use that list.php#Anohana10 to link in other pages?. because usually if you link something it  ask for file location? is that possible? like in my home.php i want to link with list.php#Anoha10